# cant perform upgrade from server 2008 standard to enterprise

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have an 32bit Windows server 2008 standard installation which I would like to upgrade to enterprise. Its a non R2 version.

The installation is Dutch. I'm using a Dutch setup disk as well (and the same Service Pack)

See: http://postimg.org/image/bad26hxmr/

[image]

It basically says: upgrades are disabled. Windows can not perform an upgrade

I can't find any logs as well.

What gives?

Comment: So you want to go from 2008 Standard to 2008 Enterprise? I'm not sure if you can do that by setup disk, but this might be of help if it applies to non-R2 version also: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825049.aspx

Comment: I know very sure , using the setup disk is the right way. This server 2008 version is based on vista and therefore doenst support the dism command

Answer (score -1):

When I've seen this issue, it's been because the Microsoft Action Pack Media has issues with the upgrade process.  Download the ISO from here and the upgrade should work.  I've tested it in Hyper-V and it worked.  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=5023